# Is it better to have 2x2GB Dual-Channel vs 4GB Single-channel RAM, performance-wise?

Tags: memory, performance, motherboard

I know this has been discussed many times before but so far I’ve only found speculations and some blurry “experiences“ on this… Many just mix single and dual channel memory, or don't care about channels at all, they mix frequencies and so on. I just want to know which will perform better as that of today in 2015:

- **A:** 2x2 GB 1600 MHz Dual Channel RAM on dual-channel slots.

versus

- **B:** 1x4 GB 1600 MHz Single Channel RAM on any kind of slot.

and finally

- **C:** 2x2GB 1600 MHz Single Channel RAM on any kind of slot.

versus

- **D:** 1x4 GB 1600 MHz Single Channel RAM on any kind of slot.

Both on a 1600 MHz-capable motherboard, of course.

Additionally, is there any performance loss between using 1333 MHz memory on a max. 1333 Mhz-capable motherbord versus using a 1600 MHz memory downscaled to 1333 MHz on the same motherboard?

Comment: dual channel is always better. With Dual Channel configuration, both ram channels can be used in parallel, to achieve the full 1600Mhz. otherwise it will run at half the advertised frequency. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Dual-channel_architecture  Also note that the RAM modules are not "single/dual/tri chanel". its the slots they are put in, that make that distinction. read your motherboard manual for specifics on how to install your RAM for dual channel.